# how to use lightbox(jquery) in gridview or datalist control

Tags: asp.net, jquery

i have an requirment where i need to i display a  **thumbnailimage** in datalist control. and once user clicks the thumbnail  image  new pop up show come showing image. along with  the data [  that  comes from **Database**]
  so any one  have done  concept using lightbox with asp.net
  any idea how to slove this thing.

i am new to jquery concept.i have no idea how to use this concept with datalist control

any help would  great 
 thank you

Answer (score 0):

I [do a similar thing](http://ksischool.com/Activities/11) with jQuery on my site but i'm using [asp.net mvc](http://asp.net/mvc) instead of classic asp.net. You should be able to inspect my jQuery in my page (its not packed so it should be easy to read).

Comment: thanks for the replay cottsak

 even i wanted to do the same thing as what you have  did. can u send me the source  code  of  it. so that it would be  usefull for me

Comment: i'm happy to give you code but i dont know what u want at this stage. my code will not work with normal asp.net, are you ok to switch to mvc?

Comment: no i need to make it work in asp.net 3.5. now even i have downloaded Lightbox jquery script .  issue is that the pop upimage comes  behind my control instead  of  coming  in front of the  page.  do have any idea.  r  did u get any such things  happened  while doing

Comment: I didn't experience that sort of problem. Maybe you can add a z-order value to the css for the lightbox container div.